# How to compare two dates values from two different forms in MS access forms

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I am working with two forms and their corresponding tables in ms access : Warranty (WarrantyDetail) and Findings(Findings). The only common field between these 2 forms is the CODE field which states the code for the PID number of the product in the warranty detail table.
When a user enters a date code in the warranty form, and if the corresponding entry in the Findings form has a FixDate which is less than the DateCode, I want to display a msgbox. I am doing this by comparing the values in the tables of these forms. However, it does not seem to work so far. Following is the code:

```
Dim Fdate
Dim FCode
FCode = DLookup("FINDINGS", "WarrantyDetail", "RGA =" & Me.RGA)
Fdate = DLookup("[FixDate]", "[Findings]", "Code =" & FCode)
'FCode = "Select WarrantyDetail.FINDINGS from WarrantyDetail where WarrantyDetail.RGA = '" + Me.RGA + "';"
'Fdate = "Select Findings.[FixDate] from Findings where Findings.[FindingsID]= '" + FCode + "';"
If Not IsNull(Fdate) Then
 If (DateValue(Me.DATECODE) > DateValue(Fdate)) Then
  MsgBox "The Fixdate precedes the Datecode"
 End If
End If
```

I am using the afterupdate event property on the DATECODE field. And looking for the fixdate for the entry which has the code same as Fcode which is obtained using another statement which looks for a code with the same RGA no. as the one which is present on the form currently. If this makes sense, please give me some pointers.
[Fields in the Findings table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMFMC.png)

[Fields in the warrantydetail table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNFsR.png)

Comment: What does "not work" mean - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? Are RGA and  Code number or text type fields? The commented SQL are using apostrophe delimiters yet they are omitted from the DLookup.

Comment: Nothing in your code shows references to a second form.

Comment: Field `DATECODE` seems named `DATECODETI`, and all values of this are _Null_, so that won't return you anything.

Comment: Yes, I want to fetch the fixdate value which has the same code as the one on the current form in warranty detail. There is no reference to the Findings form as i am referring to its table directly which also named the same. I am trying to fetch value from its table rather than the second form itself.
It doesn't give any error when I use the Dlookup commands to fetch those values. But when comment out the Dlookup commands & use the SQL select commands, it throws a run tine error '13': type mismatch on the Select statement(s). 
@Gustav wdym they are null? 
PS: I appreciate all of your replies

Comment: I am using the 
```If Not IsNull(Fdate) Then``` if statement because some of the PID's in the second form/its corresponding table do not have any fixdates at all/blank fields for the fixdate. So i am trying to handle that using this command. Open to better solutions to handle this though, if any. Thanks!

Comment: The DLookup treat RGA and Code fields as number type yet the SQL treats RGA as text type (that is probably reason for 'type mismatch' error). And the SQL isn't even using the same field in criteria for FCode. Have you step-debugged? Are the DLookup returning expected data?

Comment: @June7 while it makes sense what you say, but i don't think that's the reason because i am never intermixing the Dlookup and sql stawtements. You can see above the sql snippet is commented out. When i comment out the Dlookup and use sql statements that is when iget a type mismatch. Anyway, yes, I have step debugged and it's still being tricky with the sql statements/dlookup. Is there a way to do any better at this? Thanks!

Comment: My point is the SQL treats those fields as text type by using apostrophe delimiters and that is probably why they get 'type mismatch' error. The DLookup treats them as number type - no apostrophe delimiters.